# How to set up hierarchical relationships without using plugins / meta query

Tags: wp-query, database, query, meta-query

I'm running a large database of musical artists and their releases. I inherited the site after it running for a long time. There are currently several different custom post types, created with a Toolset plugin.

The post types are hierarchical like this
Artists | Directors |
Releases |
Albums | Singles | Videos | Misc |

Artists and Directors are parent to
Releases, which is a parent to the Version
Albums | Singles | Videos | Misc | are the four version types we have.

In order to display all this information, I have been using queries that look like this.

```
<?php 
$album_args = array(
   'post_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-release-type',
        'value' => 'album',
      ),    
    ),
);
$album_posts = types_child_posts('release', $album_args);?>
<div class="row row-cols-1   justify-content-center">
    <?php foreach ($album_posts as $child_post)  {      ?>
        <div class="col py-1">
        <?php include get_template_directory() . '/includes/containers/artist-page-container.php' ;?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I cannot find any information on types_child_posts. I know it's from Toolset plugin. I believe I'm learning that this system I'm using is slowing down my pages. An artist like Madonna has so many releases, the page times out.

There are some exceptions to the artist area of tis rule- but I'll tackle that later. Let's say for now that

An artist has a one->many relationship with releases.
Releases ALWAYS have a one->many relationship with versions.
A version is ALWAYS a child of a release.

What is a better way (is there one?) than using this plugin to set up a hierarchical relationship so I don't have to use types_child_posts or Meta_queries?

Thanks

[image: Here's a diagram of hierarchy with arrows]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136579/discussion-on-question-by-rcotwunite-how-to-set-up-hierarchical-relationships-wi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use taxonomies to store your relationships.

Sidenote: A possible answer was to make the releases children of the artists using the classic `post_parent` field, however a post can only have 1 parent, and the need for a release to also have a director and other relationships eliminates this option.

### Taxonomies

You will want to create custom taxonomies for every relationship, focusing on the phrase:

An X can have Y's

Where X's are things and Y's are groups or things you would filter and search for.

So in this case:

- Releases can have an artist

  - an artist taxonomy
- releases can have a director

  - a directory taxonomy

You will need to create a basic plugin that registers a taxonomy with these names.

To register a taxonomy, use `register_taxonomy`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/

Most people use a generator to get their initial code, e.g. I go to generatewp and fill out the form to get my starting code for a new taxonomy:

https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

The important thing here, is that we're going to use some naming trickery to tie the `madonna` artist term, to the `madonna` artist custom post type. So if I have a `Lady Gaga` artist post, and a release post named `The Fame`, then I will give "The Fame" the `lady gaga` artist term, because the Lady Gaga artist post has the slug `lady gaga` too and they match. When I want the artist I fetch the artist post with the same slug, and when I want the artists releases, I ask for all releases with an artist term of the same name.

The bonus of this is that the release posts can now have multiple artists, e.g. Lady Gagas duet album with Tony Bennet is no longer an issue for your database, and neither are compilation albums.

So let's create a custom taxonomy and call it something like `artists` ( make sure it's not the same as your post type ), then when we create our release we add a term named `madonna`, making sure it's identical to the artist posts name/slug.

Then finally, if we are on the madonna artist posts template, and want to list her releases, we might do this:

```php
$releases = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'release',
    'artists' => 'madonna'
] );
if ( $releases->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $releases->have_posts() ) {
        $releases->the_post();
        the_title(); // prints the release title
        // etc..
```

Here we've asked for all posts of type `release` that are in the `artists` taxonomy term named `madonna`. Of course you will want to fetch the slug of the current artist post so that you don't have to manually type this out for every single artist.

#### Automation filters

Of course typing out `madonna` and every other artist name twice isn't fun, and what if Madonna changes her name? What if we create a `directors` taxonomy and they get married or it's revealed they were actually someone else writing under a false name?

Well we can automate these things using hooks:

- when an artist post is saved, if the slug was changed, find the term with the same name and change its slug too

  - if no term exists, create it

```php
// when an "artist" post is saved, update the artists term
add_action( 'save_post_artist', 'update_artist_term', 10, 3 );
function update_artist_term( $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update ) : void {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $post->post_name, 'artists' );
    if ( empty( $term ) || is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        // create it!
        wp_insert_term(
            $post->post_title,
            'artists',
            [
                'slug' => $post->post_name
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

This code is just an example that creates the term but it's untested and doesn't update the slug

### Templates

Currently you're using PHP code to fetch and display the releases, but if you used taxonomies, WordPress gives you theme templates and archives for free.

If you register a taxonomy named `artists`, and used the madonna example, you'd find that a new post archive that shows releases tagged `madonna` now exists at `example.com/artists/madonna`, and that a theme template of `taxonomy-artists.php` will be used if available, or even `taxonomy-artists-madonna.php` if you felt Madonna needed special attention.

### Doing the reverse

If we're on a release, and we want to list the artists ( the benefit of this approach is a release can have many artists now ), we just need to fetch the names of the terms using `wp_get_object_terms`:

```php
$artists_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'artists' );
```

Then we can grab their names:

```php
$artist_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $artists_terms, 'slug' );
```

And do a query of the artist post type:

```php
$artists = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'artist',
    'post_name__in' => $artist_slugs,
] );
if ( $artists->have_posts() ) {
    /// etc.. standard post loop that displays each artist like before
```

### The Other Post Types

You can repeat this entire process for every other item. The most difficult part is migrating all that data over which will be frustrating.

The other thing to note:

- `tax_query` can let you do more complex queries on taxonomies, but taxonomies are not free, they're much cheaper and faster than `meta_query` but they aren't instant
- avoid `NOT` or `not_in` parameters at all costs, they're one of the slowest types of query you can do, even slower than `meta_query`, but not as slow as
- `'orderby' => 'RAND'`, will make your database copy the entire table with all your content into memory, randomly order it, then run the original query you wanted. It's the most expensive, slowest thing you can do, and also the most unnecessary. If you want a random thing just do the random part in PHP. E.g. pick a random date and ask for the first 5 things after that date, much cheaper/faster.

---

Anything you're using to filter that's just a custom field such as release type, or genre, can just be a plain standard custom taxonomy, and this is where you should focus your initial efforts. It's the easiest way to make the biggest improvement.

Comment: Note that this answer covers a lot of stuff, I expect you'll need some time to research all the things I mentioned before you'll fully understand the specifics of what you need to do. There are also a lot of potential questions that are answered by reading through the options of `register_taxonomy` and `register_post_type`, you'll find lots of existing questions on the site too

Comment: This is great, thank you. I will need to go through and digest this. I went and turned all albums into a taxonomy and replaced the meta_query with a tax_query. With just the albums section changed, madonna's page sped up by a whole second. When I do this to singles, it will be even more so effective. Thanks for this!

Comment: I've been using plugin toolset to make my taxonomies- any downside to doing it this way? It's very simple for me and seems to work correctly (as far as I know.) I didn't realize there was another way.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying- I should replace the line types_child_posts('release',$albumargs) with a tax_query where the slug is 'artistname'. Is there a way to automate moving the artist names over? Or will I need to create a new taxonomy-slug for each current artist, as well as create a new one for all future artists?

Comment: I converted all of the versions to taxonomies and took out all meta_queries on my single-artist page. It is SOOOOOO much faster. Thank you again for all your hard work helping my dense self understand all this!

Comment: automating creating terms in bulk would be a good new question! Glad it's given you a big speed boost and that you made progress so quickly!

Comment: Got it. I'll make a new question. I understand how to use this page now. Thanks Tom. I don't know how to privately contact you, are you available for-hire for a tutoring session? Please delete this post if it crosses any boundaries.

Comment: I'm not available for hire, but keep in mind that some of the new questions you've asked might be off-topic because they can't be fully answered without Toolset knowledge, and that migrating to taxonomies as a solution is something you're now aware of.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I rewrote my other question. I have 3k artists and 19k releases, I think converting those to a taxonomy is a huge undertaking for now. I'm hoping there's a simpler solution.