# How do I have multiple metaqueries inside one wordpress query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, array

I have a `parent->child` relationship between `artists` and `releases`. There is another parent->child relationship between `releases` and `versions` aka `albums, singles, videos, misc`.

So artist is the grandparent of `version`.

I'm using a wp query to find all `version` posts that belong to an artist. This works great, yay for me!

I've added some custom fields to the `release` level, including `featuring` and `related to`. I'd like this same query to pull all `versions` that belong to a `release` that has the `artist` listed in one of these fields.

My problem is, I can't wrap my head around how to include `release` post type in as well. here's my current code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('single','album','videos','misc'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'format' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-format',
                ),
                'country' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-country-of-release',
                ),
                'year' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-release-year',
                    
                ),
                'label' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-label',
                ),
                'artist' => array(
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        'mainartist'=> array(
                            'key' => $queriedartistid,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                        'splitartist'=> array(
                            'key' => $splitartist,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                        'relatedto'=> array(
                            'key' => $relatedto,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                        'featuring'=> array(
                            'key' => $featuring,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                        'performedby'=> array(
                            'key' => $performedby,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                        'variousartist'=> array(
                            'key' => $variousartist,
                        'value' => $thispostartistid,
                        ),
                    ),
                        
                ),
                'release' => array(
                    'key' => '_wpcf_belongs_release_id',
                    
                ),
                'bootleg' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-bootleg',
                ),
                
                'catalogue' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-catalogue-number',
                ),
                ),
                
            ),
        ),
    
'orderby' => array(
    'year' => 'ASC',
    'format' => 'ASC',
    'country' => 'ASC',
    'label' => 'ASC',
    'catalogue' => 'ASC',
    'other_info_empty' => 'ASC',
    'other_info_there' => 'ASC',
    )
);
```

The problem is in my artist array. The search is only looking for `versions`, which don't have the meta fields 'featuring`or`related to` etc. Those are in the version level.

How can I structure this query to include also `versions` of `releases` with the `artist` listed in these meta fields?

In English:
show all versions, where the meta-key `'_wpcf_belongs_release_id'` matches a release which has the custom meta-key `related_to` with a value of `$thispostartistid`. How can I include that in this query?

Thanks, I think this is a complicated way to write this question, looking forward to comments that help me clean up and make my question clearer.

Comment: that's going to be a stupendously slow query to run, but ignoring that, you want to perform several separate queries but smush them all into the same query to show them all at once you want to show all "A B or C that have D E F" and "X with Y and Z", which doesn't work. All the posts returned by the query have to match the arguments you pass to `WP_Query`, if you want to "combine" these things you need to make multiple queries, `WP_Query` will only perform one query.

Comment: Thanks Tom. The search is already very slow. These huge queries take several seconds to run. Maybe this is a new question, but is it possible for me to re-write the code in a smarter way to speed it up, or is it going to be slow no matter what because it's all stored as metadata?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've told you multiple times in the past exactly what you needed to do to avoid post meta queries, in extensive comments and sometimes as answers on your past questions. You even asked how to implement it and accepted one of my answers as correct here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/406090/how-to-set-up-hierarchical-relationships-without-using-plugins-meta-query

Comment: Thanks Tom, not sure I was ready to understand what you wrote before. I'm looking back into it now and it makes more sense to me this time.